# Java: Exception while connecting to remote database

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access, vps

I'm trying to connect to my remote database on my VPS using a desktop application built with JAVA.
I have granted access to my ip address by adding this line in the VPS:
[image]

After that I have created a JAVA class to test the conenction:

```
package smt.agm.launcher;
import java.sql.*;
public class Test {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://my_vps:port/my_database";

       //  Database credentials
       static final String USER = "user";
       static final String PASS = "password";

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating statement...");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
          while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name
             String col1= rs.getString("column1");
             String col2= rs.getString("column2");

             //Display values
             System.out.print("column1: " + col1 + ", column2: "+col2);
          }
          //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main

}
```

But I have faced this exception:

```
PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (5 526 600 > 65 535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

So I did some research and I have found a way to increase the variable `max_allowed_packet` using ssh:

```
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

and I have increased the value of `max_allowed_packet` to **500M**.
Unfortunately this didn't help and I've got the same exception with the same values:

```
PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (5 526 600 > 65 535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you restarted mysqld on your VPS after changing `my.cnf` ?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau yes I did `service mysql restart`.

Comment: Can you connect to the VPS, start `mysql` command line client, and run query: `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;` to verify if the setting is in effect? If not, check your `my.cnf` again, did you enter that in the right section, and is there another line with same property elsewhere in the file that would override?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau sorry for my late response, yes it gave the correct value.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a monster row in there?  Are you using BLOBs or something?  Have you tried to not do a `select *` but instead select a couple of specific fields to see if one field is the issue?

Comment: @Gray nope it's a list of users that contains about 5 users only not a big thing !

Comment: How many rows @Slimen?

Comment: @Gray as I said it's about 5 or 6 rows